# How to detect when a form is 'ready' once component initializes

Tags: angular, forms

I suspect I'm probably doing something wrong but the issue is that there are times I need to do Form or FormControl tinkering after a component is initialized and data has loaded.  What I'm finding is that the form and its controls aren't entirely initialized at either the OnInit or AfterViewInit lifecycle stages.

Excerpt of sample code:

```
@ViewChild('MyForm') form: NgForm; 
model: MyModel;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.data.subscribe(
        data => {
            const model = data['model'];
            this.initForm(model);
        },
        err => console.error(err)
    );
}

private initForm(model: MyModel): void {
    this.model = model;

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.form.form.markAsPristine();
        const myCtrl = this.form.form.get('myCtrl');
        myCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
            console.log(value);
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

Quick explanation of the order of events for my app's component: I have a Resolver in my routing module that fetches MyModel data from the backend api.  The component loads, its template's MyForm form is bound to the 'model' property of the component.  NgOnInit() is called, I retrieve the model data from the route and call initForm() to set the data on the model property.  I then need to call "markAsPristine()' on the form because the form is now dirty (even though the model itself hasn't been touched yet by the user -- which is something I don't understand btw).  Also, I need to subscribe to valueChanges on some controls to watch for specific stuff.

The problem is, the markAsPristine() and access to the inner controls of the forms won't work if I don't wrap that code in the setTimeout() function.  It's as if the form isn't quite ready and needs a moment for the framework to set it up before I can fiddle with it.  For example, without the setTimeout the "this.form.form.get('myCtrl')" will return null.  However, after the 1 second delay the FormControl does exist and is returned.

Is there some way to know when a form is 'ready'?  Or, am I doing something wrong?  Also of note: my models are VERY complex and have nested objects, arrays, and such.  So I wondering if it's due to that complexity is the reason why the form's functionality isn't immediately accessible..?

By the way, this a template based form and not a Reactive form.

Comment: You shouldn't need to mark it as pristine. Can you put together a plunker that demonstrates the issues without having to include all of your complex models?

Comment: I'll try to create a plunker demo, but I suspect that it will behave normally due to the nature of the code being simple.  What I'm experiencing feels like some sort of asynchronous framework task that hasn't complete yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jake.

You can try ngDoCheck lifecycle hook.

```
ngDoCheck(): void {
  if (this.form) ....
}
```

Hope it helps.